# HTML. When there's 2x onclick event in the same area

Tags: html, onclick

here's the situation: I have a  where in every cell all the area has a onclick event that opens a edit form, let's call this A. In the same cell, in a corner I also have an 'X' to delete the object represented in that cell, also with an onclick event in this case with a Yes/No warning, let's call this B.

When I click on the X (onclick B), it appears de dialog to confirm I want to delete or not but the problem comes whatever I trigger, I also run the onclick A because B is in the same onclick area that A.

Is there any solution so when I click on B, A does not trigger? Hope I make clear my problem.

Thanks

**Update**

Thanks to the guide http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html I just had to add this JS function

```
function doSomething(e)
{
if (!e) var e = window.event;
e.cancelBubble = true;
if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
}
```

And call it on the onclick B event before calling my other function:

```
onclick="doSomething(); Calendar.delClick('${id}', this); return false"
```

Thank you both very much ;)

Comment: @framara: please take a look at http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&q=site:quirksmode.org+Unobtrusive+javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [event bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you experiencing is event bubbling. Have a look at PPKs excellent [writing](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) in this matter.

Comment: Specifically this section: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html#link9 (and note that most libraries will implement an abstraction for you, e.g. http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/DOMEventFacade.html#method_halt )

Comment: Yeah, bugger you beat me with 20 sec ^^ +1 upvote from me to you it is.